# Determinant of the matrix with $a_{i,j}=2\delta_{i,j}-\delta_{i+1,j}-\delta_{i,j+1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

How to find the determinant of the matrix of order $n$ with $(i,j)$th entry as $$a_{i,j}=2\delta_{i,j}-\delta_{i+1,j}-\delta_{i,j+1}$$ here $\delta_{i,j}=1$ if $i=j$ and zero otherwise? I tried it for $2\times 2$ and $3\times 3$ matrices and conclude determinant as $n+1.$ But i like directly  general method to find determinant. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: The natural thing to try is to get a recurrence relation using cofactor expansion. Have you tried it?

Comment: no i write the entries only...

Comment: if possible write in answer block.....

Comment: This is a [tridiagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generalise the problem to the computation of determinants:
$$D_n(a,b)=\begin{vmatrix}
a&b&0&0&\dots&0&0\\
b&a&b&0&\dots&0&0\\
0&b&a&b&\dots&0&0\\[-1ex]
\vdots&&&\!\ddots\!&&&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&\dots&a&b\\
0&0&0&0&\dots&b&a
\end{vmatrix}$$
Develop $D_n(a,b)$ along the last row:
\begin{align*}D_n(a,b)&=-b\begin{vmatrix}
a&b&0&0&\dots&0&0\\
b&a&b&0&\dots&0&0\\
0&b&a&b&\dots&0&0\\[-1ex]
\vdots&&&\!\ddots\!&&&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&\dots&a&b
\end{vmatrix}+a D_{n-1}(a,b)\\
&=-b^2D_{n-2}(a,b)+a D_{n-1}(a,b)
\end{align*}

So one obtains a linear recurrence of order $2$, which is initialised thus:
$$D_1(a,b)=a,\quad D_2(a,b)=a^2-b^2.$$

Answer (score 3):

Expansion by cofactors is a general method to find the determinant. For your problem, this involves exactly two terms (for the two nonzero entries in the first row); the two recursive determinants are straightforward:

- the first one is just a smaller instance of the same problem (so you can use your inductive hypothesis to evaluate it)
- the second needs to be evaluated with a further cofactor expansion; one cofactor is evidently zero; the other is an even smaller instance of the same problem.

Comment: An interesting consequence of this result is that, since the eigenvalues are $2+2\cos k\pi/(n+1)$, $k=1,\ldots,n$,  $$\prod_{k=1}^n\left(2+2\cos \frac{k\pi}{n+1}\right) = n+1.$$

Comment: how you find these are eigen values???

Comment: @neela the usual approach is to hunt for eigenvectors directly, without computing the determinant.

Comment: Nice point. I only went this route because OP asked for a general method to find the determinant, and I like first of all to answer the question asked. But I should have thought of this as well.